# Need simple Express.js XML server example

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, express

I have difficulties in something that should be very simple: 
Building a simple Express.js server/listener that will receive XML file (lets's say from Postman) and parse it. 
Tried different approaches, like XML2J LibXMLjs- nothing works.

Since I am new also to Postman: please advice me also how to post the message from there. (tried Body/Raw/XML - did not work for me).

Comment: Please post code and what went wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can parse xml with [xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) like so:

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var xml = "<root>Hello xml2js!</root>";

parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
});
```

Comment: thanks. I have tried it. It works when I am reading the string as Var. But it doesn't work when it comes as a request. Can you send me a snippet of all the server side and try it with Postman? (or other external tool).

Comment: app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Got a POST request for the homepage");
    console.log(req.body);
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    res.send(req.body);
    
    var xml = new XmlStream(res.body);

    xml.preserve('book', true);
    xml.collect('subitem');
    xml.on('endElement: item', function (item) {
        console.log(item);
    });

})

Comment: That code doesn't use `xml2js`, it should work if you do it like in the example and use `req.body` as the xml string.

Comment: I have tried it also with xml2js:
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Got a POST request for the homepage");
    console.log(req.body);
    var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
    var xml = req.body

    parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
        console.dir(result);
    });

})

i get undefined.

Comment: What does it show when you `console.log(req.body)`? Also add `if (err) return console.log(err);` in the beginning of the callback function

Comment: So there is no xml. How do you post it?

Comment: via postman for instance. here is the server code to get the post data:



var express = require('express'),
        app = express(),
        http = require('http'),
        server = http.createServer(app);
app.post('/', function (req, res, next) {

    console.log("Got a GET request for the homepage");
    var xml = req.body

    parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
        console.dir(result);
    });

});

server.listen(1337);